# Properties, public or private OOP PHP

Tags: php, oop

I have the following two classes (*I have not included the interfaces*)

*ConditionsRefer*

```
namespace PG\Referrer\Single\Post;

class ConditionsRefer implements ConditionsReferInterface
{
    /**
     * @var $authorReferrer = null
     */
    private $isAuthorReferrer = null;

    /**
     * @var $dateReferrer = null
     */
    private $isDateReferrer = null;

    /**
     * @var $searchReferrer = null
     */
    private $isSearchReferrer = null;

    /**
     * @var $taxReferrer = null
     */
    private $isTaxReferrer = null;

    /**
     * @param array $values = null;
     */
     public function __construct(array $values = null)
    {
        if ($values)
        $this->setBulk($values);
    }

    /**
     * Bulk setter Let you set the variables via array or object
     */
    public function setBulk($values)
    {
        global $wp_query;

        if (!is_array($values) && !$values instanceof \stdClass) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(
                sprintf(
                    '%s needs either an array, or an instance of \\stdClass to be passed, instead saw %s',
                    __METHOD__,
                    is_object($values) ? get_class($values) : gettype($values)
                )
            );
        }

        foreach ($values as $name => $value) {//create setter from $name

            if (array_key_exists($value, $wp_query->query_vars)) { //Check that user don't set a reserved query vars
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException(
                    sprintf(
                        '%s is a reserved query_vars and cannot be used. Please use a unique value',
                        $value
                    )
                );
            }

            $setter     = 'set' . $name;
            $condition  = isset($_GET[$value]);

            if ($setter !== 'setBulk' && method_exists($this, $setter)) {
                $this->{$setter}($condition);//set value (bool)
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param $authorReferrer
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setAuthorReferrer($isAuthorReferrer)
    {
        $this->isAuthorReferrer = $isAuthorReferrer;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param $dateReferrer
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setDateReferrer($isDateReferrer)
    {
        $this->isDateReferrer = $isDateReferrer;
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * @param $searchReferrer
     * @return $this
     */
    public function isSearchReferrer($isSearchReferrer)
    {
        $this->isSearchReferrer = $isSearchReferrer;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param $taxReferrer
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setTaxReferrer($isTaxReferrer)
    {
        $this->isTaxReferrer = $isTaxReferrer;
        return $this;
    }

}
```

*QueryArgumentsRefer*

```
namespace PG\Referrer\Single\Post;

class QueryArgumentsRefer implements QueryArgumentsReferInterface
{
    private $referrer;

    public function __construct(ConditionsReferInterface $referrer, array $values = array())
    {
        $this->referrer = $referrer;
        $this->referrer->setBulk($values);
    }

    public function getReferrer()
    {
        return $this->referrer;

    }

    public function b()
    {
        $test = (object) $this->referrer;
        if($test->isAuthorReferrer === false)
            return 'This is just a test';
    }
}
```

This is how I use it in a file

```
$a = new QueryArgumentsRefer(new ConditionsRefer(), ['authorReferrer' => 'aq']);
    ?><pre><?php var_dump($a->b()); ?></pre><?php
```

In `function b()` in class `QueryArgumentsRefer`, I need to use the properties of class `ConditionsRefer`.

This is the result of `$test`, which is the expected result, so this is working

```
object(PG\Referrer\Single\Post\ConditionsRefer)#522 (4) {
  ["isAuthorReferrer":"PG\Referrer\Single\Post\ConditionsRefer":private]=>
  bool(false)
  ["isDateReferrer":"PG\Referrer\Single\Post\ConditionsRefer":private]=>
  NULL
  ["isSearchReferrer":"PG\Referrer\Single\Post\ConditionsRefer":private]=>
  NULL
  ["isTaxReferrer":"PG\Referrer\Single\Post\ConditionsRefer":private]=>
  NULL
}
```

If I try to use `$test->isAuthorReferrer`, I get the following error

> **Fatal error:** Cannot access private property PG\Referrer\Single\Post\ConditionsRefer::$isAuthorReferrer

which is expected I guess. The only way to make this work in my mind is setting the properties in `ConditionsRefer` to `public`

I've read properties should be `private`, and not `public`. How can I properly work around this problem, or do I **have to** make my properties `public`

### EDIT

I have tried setting my properties to `protected`, but that does noet help as this also gives me a fatala error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve this issue. I'm still new to OOP and had a slight misunderstanding about setters and getter.

What I did is, I created a getter for each setter in the *ConditionsRefer* class, and instead of trying to use the properties of this class in the *QueryArgumentsRefer* class (which caused the initial error), I used the getters to get my info from the *ConditionsRefer* class inside the *QueryArgumentsRefer* class like

```
$this->conditionalReferrer->isAuthorReferrer();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `protected` and your child classes can use it. This way you can still have access to it in children classes without making it `public`. `private` means only the base class may use it.

Also, as a side note, all variables in a class without a default value will default to `null`

```
/**
 * @var $authorReferrer = null
 */
protected $isAuthorReferrer;
```

Comment: You changed all the `private` to `protected` and still got an error about `private`?

Comment: I still get a fatal error, but for `protected`, almost the same error as with `private`